# Hyperledger Fabic 2.2.0 Error handling success response. Value did not match schema

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I am using Hyperledger Fabric 2.2.0 and fabric-network 2.1 (not that important).

My chaincode is written in Go. So I have some structs which have `,omitempty` in JSON tag. Here is my struct:

```
type LeaseDetails struct {
    EndOfTerm string `json:"endOfTerm"`
    Info      string `json:"info,omitempty"`
    Option    string `json:"option,omitempty"`
}
```

But I am getting the following error as a return value from my chaincode:

```
peer=peer0.org1.example.com:7051, status=500, message=Error handling success response. Value did not match schema:
1. return.0.leaseDetails: info,omitempty is required
2. return.0.leaseDetails: option,omitempty is required
```

If I remove `,omitempty` from my struct, and provide default value everything works fine.
In the docs for `fabric-contract-api-go` it is mentioned that there is some kind of serializer built upon json marshal/unmarshal, but to me it doesn't seem to detect the `,omitempty` keyword.

Was this intentional? Or am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the answer on [Hyperledger Chat](https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric-questions?msg=auZG5vWf5RChmewxW) from user @awjh.

> This is as intended, the json is compared against the metadata schema.
> By default all fields are required, using omitempty will mean that the
> JSON process will remove that field when it has no value. This means a
> required field will be missing. To fix this add a metadata tag to mark
> the field as optional `metadata:",optional"`

So in my case, the solution is:

```
type LeaseDetails struct {
    EndOfTerm string `json:"endOfTerm"`
    Info      string `json:"info,omitempty" metadata:",optional"`
    Option    string `json:"option,omitempty" metadata:",optional"`
}
```